# SQL Syntax Error Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a sql syntax and it gives me the error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'VEHICLEMASTR.cconduction'
>   is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here is the SQL syntax:

```
SELECT A.cplateno,A.cconduction,A.cname,A.cbatterymodel
,A.dbattery,A.DlastChange,A.nlastoilkm,A.naveragekmday
,A.dkmreading,A.dfranacq,A.dfranexp,A.nlimit,A.dreading
,CONVERT(varchar(2),month(MAX(B.dinsexp)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(2),day(MAX(B.dinsexp)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(4),year(MAX(B.dinsexp))) as dinsexp
,C.corno,CONVERT(varchar(2),month(MAX(C.dregexp)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(2),day(MAX(C.dregexp)))+'/'+  CONVERT(varchar(4),year(MAX(C.dregexp))) as dregexp 
FROM VEHICLEMASTR A 
LEFT JOIN VEHICLEINSURANCE B 
ON A.cplateno = B.cplateno 
LEFT JOIN VREGISTRATION C 
ON A.cplateno = C.cplateno 
GROUP BY A.cplateno
```

Can anybody tell what went wrong?

Comment: You can't put all the columns in the select statement when you are doing grouping functions.  You have to put them in the group by clause or have some type of function (like count) to enable them to be there.

Comment: Put that **VEHICLEMASTR.cconduction** field too into group by. Because if you are using any aggregate function then all the selected list of columns must have in Group by clause.

Comment: i just need to group the cplateno column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "group by" clause must name every column selected, except those columns that are aggregate functions.

FYI an "aggregate" function is one that returns a single value for many rows, like sum(), count(), etc

Comment: in other words... i should put all columns in a group by statement? correct?

Comment: Yes. Basically copy paste your select clause into the group by clause and delete the aggravated values

Answer (score 0):

a.cconduction needs to be in the group by clause.

When using a `Group By` clause, a column must either have an aggregate function (i.e. COUNT) or be defined in the group by.

A sample group by statement with multiple grouping:

```
SELECT column1_name, column2_name, aggregate_function(column_name3)
 FROM table_name
 WHERE column_name1 operator value
 GROUP BY column_name1, column_name2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include all fields that you mentioned in your select except the column that has aggregate function so in your case it would be:

```
GROUP BY 
a.cplateno, a.cconduction,a.cname,a.cbatterymodel,a.dbattery,
a.DlastChange,a.nlastoilkm,a.naveragekmday, 
a.dkmreading,a.dfranacq,a.dfranexp,a.nlimit,a.dreading
```

instead of

```
GROUP BY a.cplateno
```

**Edit**:

If you want only the `a.cplateno` then you don't include the rest of the fields except `aggregate function` and `a.cplateno` like:

```
SELECT  A.cplateno
,CONVERT(varchar(2),month(MAX(B.dinsexp)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(2),day(MAX(B.dinsexp)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(4),year(MAX(B.dinsexp))) as dinsexp 
,CONVERT(varchar(2),month(MAX(C.dregexp)))+'/'+CONVERT(varchar(2),day(MAX(C.dregexp)))+'/'+  CONVERT(varchar(4),year(MAX(C.dregexp))) as dregexp 
FROM VEHICLEMASTR A 
LEFT JOIN VEHICLEINSURANCE B 
ON A.cplateno = B.cplateno 
LEFT JOIN VREGISTRATION C 
ON A.cplateno = C.cplateno 
GROUP BY A.cplateno
```

Comment: @JesunBicar yes, i didn't see that for such a loooonnnnggg query ;-)